# React-router: prevent navigation callback

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4.

In a popup i have, i want that when user press the back button it closes the dialog and not navigate back.

Is there any way to listen to navigation changes and prevent them to happen?

Comment: Well, i would i achieve it this way. Lets assume that you are on path `/user/view/`. When you wanna open the popup, navigate to different url like `/user/view/change-password` which loads a subcomponent(`dialog`) as a child in the same component. When the user navigates back, the dialog disappears.

Comment: It can work that way, the thing is, i am doing a generic component for kinda a dropdown, that opens a popup when you click it.
Letting you select an item. But user may end up pressing the back button, on the phone, expecting it to close, but what happens is that you go to previous route.
I manage to fix that in cordova listening to backbutton event.
But i would like to have this working in the mobile web version.